# How to make YouTube and Vimeo Videos Responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I want to make embedded video from youtube and vimeo responsive.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Responsive YouTube and Vimeo Videos

## 1. Get the Vimeo Embed Code

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://vimeo.com/176291464" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

## 2. Use the Embed Code

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://vimeo.com/176291464" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

## 3.Modify the Embed Code

```
<div class="video-responsive">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://vimeo.com/176291464" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Add the CSS

```
.video-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.video-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```css
.embed-container { 
position: relative;  
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
height: 0; 
overflow: hidden; 
max-width: 100%; 
height: auto; 
} 
.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { 
position: absolute; 
top: 0; 
left: 0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
}
```

```html
  <div class='embed-container'><iframe src='https://player.vimeo.com/video/11712103' frameborder='0' webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>
```